# jQuery syntax not setting object property

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery question I beleive is pretty simple, which is driving me insane that I can't get it.

I have an object with a property "content", I want to be able to take that object, manipulate the property "content" with jQuery and then overwrite the value with the new value jQuery creates.

Example:

```
o.content = "<div><span>hello</span></div>";
$('div', o.content).addClass('test');
```

At this point I want o.content to be equal to `<div class='test'><span>hello</span></div>`

I can not for the life of me figure out the syntax. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell what you want to do, please rephrase. What do you think the second parameter to `$('div', param)` does? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: So you want an HTML string or a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs of the jquery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), `context` must be

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Your context (`o.content`) is a string. Also, the jQuery function is not able to select the entire context, it can only select elements in that context.

Try this instead:

```
// make o.content a jquery element, not a string
o.content = $("<div><span>hello</span></div>");

// select on something inside the context (inside the div), not the div itself
$('span', o.content).addClass('test');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JfW4Q/

Answer (score 2):

Parse the html in `o.content`, add the class, append the parsed html to a new `<div>`, and get the html of the new div:

```
o.content = "<div><span>hello</span></div>";
var el = $(o.content).addClass('test');
o.content = $("<div>").append(el).html();
```

**Edit:** This assumes you want `o.content` to still contain a string, rather than a jQuery object.  In that case, it's simpler:

```
o.content = $(o.content).addClass('test');
```

Comment: This could possibly be what the OP wanted, do you have a crystal ball?

Comment: @JuanMendes - He said he wants `o.content` to change from `"<div><span>hello</span></div>"` to `"<div class='test'><span>hello</span></div>"`.  This does that.  That is, assuming he wants a string and not a jQuery object.  If [Musa's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424145/jquery-syntax-not-setting-object-property#comment18346763_13424145) is addressed, we'll find out.

Comment: I was just marveling at how you figured that out from the question (now that it's been rephrased, it's easier to see it)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a string `<div class="test"><span>hello</span></div>` if this is what you want:

```
$(o.content).addClass('test').wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can lookup an element from a string like that.. I would rather do it like below,

```
var content = "<span>hello</span>";
content = $('<div/>', {class: 'test'}).html(content)
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4e5z/

Answer (score 1):

You want the following

```
o.content = "<div><span>hello</span></div>";
// Create a jQuery object you can call addClass on
var docFragment = $(o.content);
docFragment.addClass('test');
// Since there's no outerHTML in jQuery, append it to another node
var wrapper = $('div');
docFragment.appendTo(wrapper);
// The HTML of the wrapper is the outerHTML of docFragment
console.log(wrapper.html()); // outputs <div class='test'><span>hello</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it all in one line:

```
var o = {};
o.content = $( "<div></div>" )     // create element
    .addClass('test')              // add class
    .html( '<span>hello</span>' ); // append content
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/eQmar/

Answer (score 1):

```
o.content = $("<div><span>hello</span></div>");
o.content.addClass('test');
```

o.content is a jQuery object in this example, as opposed to just a string.  Here's a demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvbsm/1/